# Is it proper to use nested loops a lot in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, cryptography, nested-loops

I have a project and I am trying to do a complex cryptographic method. Is it normal to use nested loops a lot? Or did I miss something?

I intend to create a method which tries all strings to find password. For example, when I input `['A','B']` it should create each of these one by one:

```
['A', 'B', 'AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB', 'AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB', (triple permutations), (quadruple permutations), and it goes on ...]
```

My code:

```
def rulefinder():
global externalrul1
global externalrul2
rul2 = uniquestring1[0]
rul1 = uniquestring1[0]
for n in range (0,3):
 for m in range (0, len(uniquestring1)):
  for z in range(0, n+1):
    for k in range (0,3):
        for i in range(0, len(uniquestring1)):
            for o in range(0, k+1):
                for y in range (0,  len(uniquestring1)):
                    rul2 = rul2[:-1] + uniquestring1[y]
                    for x in range (0, len(uniquestring1)):
                        rul1= rul1[:-1] + uniquestring1[x]
                        code=""
                        for cha in Genx1:
                            if cha==uniquestring1[0]:
                                code +=codereplacer(rul1)
                            elif cha==uniquestring1[1]:
                                code +=codereplacer(rul2)
                        print(code)
                        print(uniquestring1[0],rul1)
                        print(uniquestring1[1],rul2)
                        print(LastString)
                        if code == LastString:
                            axiom1=uniquestring1[0]
                            axiom2=uniquestring1[1]
                            externalrul1=rul1
                            externalrul2=rul2
                            print('rules are found')
                            print("First RULE:", uniquestring1[0], rul1)
                            print("Second RULE:", uniquestring1[1], rul2)
                            findsubgeneration(code, axiom1, rul1, axiom2, rul2)
                            return
                rul1 = rul1[:o] + uniquestring1[i] + rul1[(o + 1):]
        rul1 += codereplacer(uniquestring1[i])
    rul2 = rul2[:z] + uniquestring1[m] + rul2[(z + 1):]
    rul1 =""
 rul2 += codereplacer(uniquestring1[m])
```

Comment: It is a sign of code smell to nest a lot of for loops, look into the `itertools` module.

Comment: As @FranciscoCouzo hinted, you might find this other thread interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/104420/289011

Comment: I have checked them but they do not include some features. For example, 'AA', 'BB', 'CC' cannot be created by 'permutation' method.

Comment: @VuralErdogan are you intending to join these permutations into strings at the end? Like so: ['A', 'B', 'AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB', 'AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB',...] or do you want to keep them as tuples like you described in the question?

Comment: @FatihAkici ['A', 'B', 'AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB', 'AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB'] is exactly what I expect when I enter 'A', 'B'. I just tried to use my own method; however, it is not efficient way. Also, it shows some errors when I increase number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things in a very MATLAB-ic way (lots of loops, and iterating only on the index, instead of elements of iterables). Pythonic way is much more efficient (uses generators under the hood), and is much cleaner:

```
import itertools
l = ['A','B']
n = 5 # The size of your "expanding permutations"
res = []
for i in range(1,n):
    res.extend(map(''.join, list(itertools.product(l, repeat=i))))
print res
```

Result:

```
['A', 'B', 'AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB', 'AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB',
'AAAA', 'AAAB', 'AABA', 'AABB', 'ABAA', 'ABAB', 'ABBA', 'ABBB', 'BAAA', 'BAAB', 'BABA', 'BABB', 'BBAA', 'BBAB', 'BBBA', 'BBBB']
```

Caution: As long as you are working with a small list, you should be fine but as `l` grows, the result is going to grow exponentially, and may eat out your memory. Hence, instead of doing an `extend` to the `res` list, you can write the results inside the loop into disk, on the fly.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try this for the project.

Comment: You are very welcome, @VuralErdogan! I am glad I could help. Basarilar! :)